# How to make Xlookup to look for a date on Table Headers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like create a formula to find value by given ID and Date. However Date is a Table1's headers. Xlookup won't recognize them. How should I fix this? Or Is there other formula to work around this problem? Thank you very much

The formula that I used is:

```
   =XLOOKUP(I3,Table1[ID],XLOOKUP(I4,Table1[[#Headers],[Wed 01-01-2020]:[Sun 05-01-2020]],Table1[[Wed 01-01-2020]:[Sun 05-01-2020]]))
```

Update!: I have successful get return value by
(1) Delete ddd (day name) from headers
(2) Put numbervalue() on both I4 and Column header in xlookup formula
But still, it seems not recognize header as date if has day name. Can it possibly put day name and get return value too.

[image]

Comment: Index and Match are your friends =). [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dynamic-arrays-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) is some short explanation on the two functions.

Comment: Thank you. JvdV. But the issue is not spill error. Even using index and match, it doesn't reconize dates in tabe header, because they have day name (ddd, eg Mon, Wed), while I4 is date format.

Comment: @AsawinWu you are going about it backwards: the table headers can only be strings, that's a limitation of Tables. If you turn the input Date into a similarly formated string using `TEXT` then the xlookup will work.  see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you created the Table from a range that incleded Headers that were Formatted Dates, you would have got a warning that

[image]

So, those headers are no longer Dates.  When you do a lookup into those headers you need to treat them as strings.

Try this version

```
=XLOOKUP(I3,Table1[ID],XLOOKUP(TEXT(I4,"ddd dd-mm-yyy"),Table1[[#Headers],[Wed 01-01-2020]:[Sun 05-01-2020]],Table1[[Wed 01-01-2020]:[Sun 05-01-2020]]))
```

FYI, it can be simplified a little to

```
=XLOOKUP(I3,Table1[ID],XLOOKUP(TEXT(I4,"ddd dd-mm-yyy"),Table1[#Headers],Table1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following formula. `Table Headers` and `I4` cell must be true date format otherwise it will not match.

```
=INDEX(Table1,MATCH(I3,Table1[ID],0),AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A:F)/(Table1[#Headers]=I4),1))
```

[image]